# При использовании интерфейса как дженерика для List, столкнулся с тем, что изменение объекта B приводит к изменениям объекта А

Tags: java, list, интерфейс, generics

Преамбула такова, хотел наполнить List 2-мя объектами с одним общим предком-интерфейсом (HasSocr)

Но, мне необходимо было сделать проверку на то, что после изменения объекты не остались равны и стали разными, дабы их можно было отдать в транзакцию на update.

```java
private List<HasSocr> getFilledResultList(List<HasSocr> entityList) {
        List<HasSocr> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++) {
            HasSocr oldHasSocr = entityList.get(i);
            HasSocr newHasSocr = entityList.get(i);
            if (oldHasSocr != null && newHasSocr != null) {
                if (newHasSocr.getSocr() != null) {
                    newHasSocr.setSocrName(newHasSocr.getSocr().getFullName());
                    newHasSocr.setSocrShort(newHasSocr.getSocr().getScName());
                    if (!hasSocrEquals(oldHasSocr, newHasSocr)) {
                        resultList.add(entityList.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }

private boolean hasSocrEquals(HasSocr oldHasSocr, HasSocr newHasSocr) {
        return oldHasSocr != null
                && newHasSocr != null
                && oldHasSocr.getSocrName().equals(newHasSocr.getSocrName())
                && oldHasSocr.getSocrShort().equals(newHasSocr.getSocrShort())
                && newHasSocr.getSocr().getScName().equals(oldHasSocr.getSocr().getScName())
                && newHasSocr.getSocr().getFullName().equals(oldHasSocr.getSocr().getFullName());
    }
```

Но обнаружил что объекты при использовании

```java
hasSocrEquals(oldHasSocr, newHasSocr)
```

всегда являются одинаковыми, и больше всего меня повергло в шок то, что если пройти по строчно в дебаге, то видно что:

```java
newHasSocr.setSocrName(newHasSocr.getSocr().getFullName());
```

Меняет значение поля SocrName и для объекта oldHasSocr. Отсюда и вопрос - почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде

```java
HasSocr oldHasSocr = entityList.get(i);
HasSocr newHasSocr = entityList.get(i);
```

обе ссылки `oldHasSocr` и `newHasSocr` относятся к одному и тому же *i*-ому элементу списка `entityList`, то есть к одному и тому же объекту, следовательно фактически у вас выполнится тождественное равенство `oldHasSocr == newHasSocr`.

Соответственно, это и есть причина того, что все изменения в объекте, на который ссылается `newHasSocr` отразятся и по ссылке `oldHasSocr` -- объект один и тот же.

Как минимум вам следовало обращаться к объектам по разным индексам типа `i` и  `i + 1`, при условии что список заполнен корректно *разными* экземплярами.